# Markdown Tiny Subset --- Lists?

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize, markdown

I prefer latex greatly to markdown, but a few of markdown's feature would make writing more pleasant.  In particular, I would love to write

```
\section{My List}

* List A
  - List A.1
* List B
```

I experimented with the `markdown.sty` package (hybrid option), but neither did I really manage to get this working (the indented version was ignored), nor do I relish enabling shell access.

Is there a more lightweight solution?  Does TeX even have the intrinsic ability to translate `'^\*'` and `'^\s\s\-'` and `'^\s\s\s\s.'` (perl regexes) into properly fenced itemize's?

I suspect the answer is no, but I have been surprised in the past by what latex could do.

Comment: "- List A.1" must be indented four spaces (not only two). I have no idea of what you mean with  the "intrinsic ability to translate perl regexes"  but guessing that mean type that code in a monospaced font, is just mark the code as you did in the question, quoting with grave accents (`), not with apostrophes  (').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of (a) a Lua function which does most of the works and (b) a couple of LaTeX utility macros -- called `\ListMarkdownOn` and `\ListMarkdownOff` -- which activate and deactivate the Lua function. By "activation", I mean assigning the Lua function to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, which makes it act like a preprocessor on the input stream, *before* TeX gets to start its usual processing. Thus, TeX won't get to "see" the `*` and `-` markdown elements if `\ListMarkdownOn` is in effect.

The main assumptions regarding the input stream are:

- If `*` occurs at the very start of an input line, the line is a Level-one list item
- If the input line starts with two or more spaces followed by `-`, the line is a level-two list item.
- Level-2 lists occur only inside level-1 lists. (In the Lua code shown below, this assumption implies that if the `InLevel2` Boolean variable is true, so is the Boolean variable `InLevel1`.)
- There are no blank lines in a list environment. Put differently: If either `InLevel1` or `InLevel2` is true, an all-blank line is interpreted as terminating all list levels.

[image]

---

The following material should be stored in a LaTeX style file called `listmarkdown.sty`. The main tex file should load the `listmarkdown` package via a `\usepackage` statement.

```
%% listmarkdown.sty
\ProvidesPackage{listmarkdown}[2020-10-26]

%% Create a bespoke two-level itemize-type list environment
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{label=\textasteriskcentered} % marker: asterisk
\setlist[myitemize,2]{label=\textendash} % marker: endash

%% Now the Lua code
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
-- Create two Boolean variables
local InLevel1 = false
local InLevel2 = false

-- Create two string variables, with beginnings of Level-1 and -2 lines
-- ["^" denotes start of line; "%s" denotes "whitespace char."]
-- [must escape literal uses of "*" and "-".]
local Level1Line = "^%*"
local Level2Line = "^%s%s%s-%-"

function listmarkdown ( s )

  if InLevel2==true then
    if s:find ( Level2Line ) then 
      s = s:gsub ( Level2Line , "\\item " )
    elseif s:find ( Level1Line ) then 
      InLevel2=false             -- fall back one list level
      s = s:gsub ( Level1Line , "\\end{myitemize} \\item " )
    else -- line doesn't start with either '*' or '  -';
         -- hence, terminate both list levels
      InLevel2=false
      InLevel1=false
      s = "\\end{myitemize}\\end{myitemize}" .. s
    end

  elseif InLevel1==true then
    if s:find ( Level2Line ) then -- start a level-2 list
      InLevel2=true
      s = s:gsub ( Level2Line , "\\begin{myitemize}\\item " )
    elseif s:find ( Level1Line ) then -- line starts with "*"
      s = s:gsub ( Level1Line , "\\item " )
    else -- line doesn't start with either '*' or '  -'
         -- hence, terminate the level-1 list
      InLevel1=false 
      s = "\\end{myitemize}" .. s
    end

  -- What to do if 'InLevel2' and 'InLevel1' are both 'false'
  elseif s:find ( Level1Line ) then -- start a level-1 list
      InLevel1=true
      s = s:gsub ( Level1Line , "\\begin{myitemize}\\item" )
  end
  return s -- return 's', for further processing by TeX
end
```

```latex
\end{luacode}


% Finally, two LaTeX macros to activate and deactivate the Lua function

\newcommand\ListMarkdownOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback 
    ( "process_input_buffer", listmarkdown , "listmarkdown" )}}

\newcommand\ListMarkdownOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback 
    ( "process_input_buffer", "listmarkdown" )}}
```

---

And here's how the code in `listmarkdown.sty` might be used within a tex file -- note that it's necessary to use LuaLaTeX.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listmarkdown}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Hello.\strut

%% Show expected look of two-level list:

\hrule 
\begin{myitemize}
\item Item A
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item Item A.1
  \end{myitemize}
\item Item B
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item Item B.1
  \item Item B.2
  \end{myitemize}
\end{myitemize}

\h rule
% Lua function not yet activated, hence no prettification

* Item A
  - Item A.1
* Item B
  - Item B.1
    - Item B.2

\hrule
\ListMarkdownOn  % Activate the Lua function -- prettification will kick in

* Item A
  - Item A.1
* Item B
  - Item B.1
    - Item B.2

\hrule
\ListMarkdownOff 
% Lua function is de-activated -- no more prettification

* Item A
  - Item A.1
* Item B
  - Item B.1
    - Item B.2

\hrule

% Say goodbye.
\noindent
Goodbye.\strut
\end{document}
```